# Make a call on double tap of power button

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android and trying to develop an application for quick help. As soon as the user double taps power button, I want my application to call the ambulance directly for both cases (Screen on/off). I have written this code but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance. :)

**Android.manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyCallService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**MyCallService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyCallService extends Service {
    public MyCallService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Created by Kinjal on 2/18/2018.
 */

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static int countPowerOff=0;
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
    private static final int code=1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.v("onReceive","Power button is pressed");

        Toast.makeText(context,"power button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            countPowerOff++;
            Toast.makeText(context,"Screen off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(countPowerOff==2){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},code);

                }

                else{
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "108")));
                }


            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                countPowerOff++;
                Toast.makeText(context,"Screen on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(countPowerOff==2){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},code);

                    }

                    else{
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "108")));
                    }


                }
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
                Log.e("LOB","userpresent");
                Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyCallService.class)); //a call to start Service
```

Comment: Follow [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559755/4168607) .and check for double tap .

Comment: @ADM this is not useful. I am able to call onReceive method and get those toasts. I have problem in making call. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: What call ? the Device default call ? or `VOIP`?

Comment: Device default call. I want my application to call the ambulance even though screen is on or off on double tap of power button.

Comment: Okk . i don't have much idea about how you can get Power button action in locked mode maybe you need to have System level permission for that . Maybe some expert will advise you . Keep Digging .

Comment: Ok. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this

```
    static int i=0;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
       i++;
        if(i==2){
    //do something
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
    startActivity(intent);
    i = 0;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```